# problem with quotes while using input-> in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, post, validation, htmlspecialchars

I am using input->post to get data in my codeigniter project. I was assuming that this will automatically filter quotes and i don't need to use addslashes() / htmlspecialchars() functions.

But it don't check for quotes.

I tried also to edit core>input.php but didn't help. Enabling XXS in config also don't help.

Suggest me easy way to filter quotes so that I don't have to edit in all my pages.

Answer (score 0):

the xss cleaner lives in `system/libraries/Security.php` in a method called `xss_clean()`

id say your best bet is to extend this class (i.e. create a `application/libraries/MY_Security.php`) 
then override this method with one which also removes quotes.